# Can I save custom information in my JWT token?

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, jwt, token, keycloak

I would like to know if there is a way to store "custom" information in my JWT token.

Right now I have a REALM created in Keycloak, then when I login against Keycloak, I get my access_token. If I decode my access_token, (from jwt.io) I obtain information like:

```
{
  "exp": 1656952366,
  "iat": 1656916366,
  "jti": "be89285a-dce9-4860-9849-396044b34578",
  "iss": "https://dev.domain.com/auth/realms/miREALM",
  "aud": "account",
  "sub": "95fa9b26-0fc8-48ac-820e-71cb70183c6b",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "MyProject",
  "session_state": "ceb61406-as9c-47f4-1461-43a63ebf939d",
  "acr": "1",
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "default-roles-myproduct-myproject",
      "offline_access",
      "uma_authorization"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "MyProject": {
      "roles": [
        "admin"
      ]
    },
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "openid mapPermissions profile email",
  "realm-management": {},
  "email_verified": false,
  "security-admin-console": {},
  "MyPRoject": {},
  "preferred_username": "administrator@mail.com",
  "account-console": {},
  "given_name": "Mark",
  "broker": {},
  "name": "Mark",
  "admin-cli": {},
  "family_name": "Mark",
  "email": "administrador@mail.com",
  "account": {}
}
```

I would like to know if there is any way to create some node with custom information.
For example, I would like to be able to save the address where the user lives, so I don't have to access my database to retrieve it.

Comment: Sure you can have a custom attribute defined for user and retrieve it. But why are you doing that? If that information is going to get updated why not store it in your application db instead of authentication db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a mapper to the client/client scope.
There are different types that you can use. In your case "User Attribute" will be the best choise.